# How can I use Ajax and Jquery to load data into a div then, insert form data and reload the data into the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I have been struggling for a couple of weeks trying to solve this. Any help would be appreciated. 
I would like to use Jquery and Ajax to create a Div element to show the number of items that are in a customers basket. When the page loads I would like the Div to show "Your basket contains 0 items". As the user clicks the add button the data is sent to a PHP page to so that an item is added to the database. Then a row count is run on another page (which will then show the number of items in the basket). 
I can easily to get the code to run when breaking it down into individual parts, but when complied and added together the code does not refresh the Div the first time button is clicked. When clicked the second time it works fine. I have looked at Google Chromes developer tools and can see that the code is working as I would like and expect. I am hoping it is something simple but it is driving me mad.

P.s My form is using a name field at the moment and does not relate to the add to basket function. I will amend this once I have the code working.

In a nutshell I would like to: 
1) load data to a div once the page has loaded.
2) When a user clicks the submit button insert data into a MySQL table
3) Reload the data into the div.

```
<script>
    $(function(){   
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });     
 $("#get_data").load("../admin/data.php");//load initial page

 $("#button1").click(function(){//when clicked insert data intoo DB and reload the page
 $.post( "insert_data.php", $( "#name" ).serialize() ); 
    $.ajax({
    url: "../admin/data.php",
    cache:false,
            })
.done(function( html ) {
$( "#get_data" ).append( html ); //show the data in the get_data div        
        });// close done function
        $( "#get_data" ).empty();

    }); 
});
```

```
User Name<br/>
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your User Name" autofocus/><br>

<input class="btn btn-blk navbar-btn" type="button" id="button1" value="Add Name To DB" /><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try and help clean this up a bit.

When the document is ready, you want to load some initial data (which I assume includes the cart contents). No problem so far;  `$("#get_data").load("../admin/data.php");` is probably working.

When the user clicks a button you want a request to be made to the server.  You have 2 requests in your code (one of them doesn't have a method, I think jQuery default is `GET`). I would recommend combining these calls, so the response of the `$.post()` returns the necessary HTML to append.

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(e){
    $.post("insert_data.php", $("#name").serialize()).done(function(html){
        $("#get_data").append( html );
    });
});
```

Of course for that to work, you'd need to change your PHP code to echo the appropriate HTML after the query but I assume one of the problems might be that the `GET` might finish before `POST` is done processing, thereby returning the value too quickly.

Comment: Amazing. Your code has solved the issue for me, as you recommended I changed the PHP code and it is working exactly as intended. I am new to this and am still a little unsure as to where  "(one of them doesn't have a method, I think jQuery default is GET)." could be coming into play. Works a dream tho. Thank you so much.